Confusion about divergence theorem for flux computation
I want to compute the flux of the vector field
$$
F = \frac{\langle x,y,z\rangle}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}
$$
over the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.
I know this is
$$
\iint F\cdot n \, dS
$$
where $n$ is the unit normal to the sphere,
$$
n = \frac{\langle x,y,z\rangle}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}. 
$$
From here I got that the flux is just the surface area of the sphere, so $4\pi$. However, using the divergence theorem, the flux should equal the integral over the volume of the sphere of the divergence of $F$, and I calculated that $\operatorname{div}(F)=0$, but the flux is non zero? I'm confused. Any help is appreciated.

The vector field is not defined at the origin, and it doesn’t have a continuous extension to the origin, let alone a $C^1$ extension to the origin, which is what you’d need for the divergence theorem. So long story short, you’re applying a theorem when one of the key hypotheses is not satisfied, i.e the theorem is not applicable here.

Of course, how did I not see that. Thank you!

Hi @peek-a-boo, will you copy-paste your comment as an answer so the question can be marked Answered?

The divergence theorem can still be made to work here if we allow ourselves to use the Dirac delta function.

Does this answer your question? Is the Gauss Divergence theorem applicable when the Divergence of a vector field is a dirac delta function?

@JohnBarber well it’s not that the divergence theorem is still true (a statement which has irked me since I first read it in Griffiths), but rather we extend our definition of what divergence means (as shown in the link of Kurt G’s comment), to consider it in the more general distributional sense, and as a result the ‘divergence theorem’ for these distributional things is essentially tautological (the non-trivial thing being the proof that the distributional divergence really is the Dirac delta). Perhaps I’m just being picky, but I think it’s important to not conflate the two.

Imho there are two equally legit views: 1) divergence theorem is not valid due to the singularity at $0,.$ 2) divergence theorem needs to be "fixed" by a Dirac delta at $0$. The reason why physicists like the latter so much is because the potential that leads to $F$ is the Newton gravitational or Coulomb potential coming from a point mass resp. a point charge.

Just getting this out of the unanswered pile: the vector field is not defined at the origin, and it doesn’t have a continuous extension to the origin, let alone a $C^1$ extension to the origin, which is what you’d need for the divergence theorem. So long story short, you’re applying a theorem when one of the key hypotheses is not satisfied, i.e the theorem is not applicable here.
